# What is causing a kernel panic on my macbook everyday?

Tags: kernel-panic

Below is the report.

```
Anonymous UUID:       641FB344-A0CE-0E5A-45AF-84776D6ABC21

Fri Sep  2 00:39:47 2016

*** Panic Report ***
Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000000000c0a
 family: 6 model: 70 stepping: 1 microcode: 19
 signature: 0x40661
 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4870HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz
 10 error-reporting banks
Processor 0: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC7_STATUS(0x41d): 0xbe00000000401137
 IA32_MC7_ADDR(0x41e):   0x00000000feb84d00
 IA32_MC7_MISC(0x41f):   0x000002f905000086
Processor 1: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC7_STATUS(0x41d): 0xbe00000000401137
 IA32_MC7_ADDR(0x41e):   0x00000000feb84d00
 IA32_MC7_MISC(0x41f):   0x000002f905000086
Processor 2: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC7_STATUS(0x41d): 0xbe00000000401137
 IA32_MC7_ADDR(0x41e):   0x00000000feb84d00
 IA32_MC7_MISC(0x41f):   0x000002f905000086
Processor 3: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC7_STATUS(0x41d): 0xbe00000000401137
 IA32_MC7_ADDR(0x41e):   0x00000000feb84d00
 IA32_MC7_MISC(0x41f):   0x000002f905000086
Processor 4: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC7_STATUS(0x41d): 0xbe00000000401137
 IA32_MC7_ADDR(0x41e):   0x00000000feb84d00
 IA32_MC7_MISC(0x41f):   0x000002f905000086
Processor 5: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC7_STATUS(0x41d): 0xbe00000000401137
 IA32_MC7_ADDR(0x41e):   0x00000000feb84d00
 IA32_MC7_MISC(0x41f):   0x000002f905000086
Processor 6: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC7_STATUS(0x41d): 0xbe00000000401137
 IA32_MC7_ADDR(0x41e):   0x00000000feb84d00
 IA32_MC7_MISC(0x41f):   0x000002f905000086
Processor 7: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC7_STATUS(0x41d): 0xbe00000000401137
 IA32_MC7_ADDR(0x41e):   0x00000000feb84d00
 IA32_MC7_MISC(0x41f):   0x000002f905000086
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff80095cf1ba): "Machine Check at 0xffffff80095ed0ab, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000700000117000, CR3: 0x000000000d825000, CR4: 0x00000000001627e0\n" "RAX: 0x0000000000000033, RBX: 0xffffff8009cf8140, RCX: 0x0000000000000001, RDX: 0x0000000000000000\n" "RSP: 0xffffff91fd70bef0, RBP: 0xffffff91fd70bf20, RSI: 0x0000000000000002, RDI: 0xffffff8009c2cec0\n" "R8:  0x0000000000000008, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0x0000000000000001\n" "R12: 0x0000000000000033, R13: 0x0000000000000001, R14: 0x0000024895bebc91, R15: 0x0000000000000000\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000046, RIP: 0xffffff80095ed0ab, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.60.10/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:168
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81e9af5e90 : 0xffffff80094dab52 
0xffffff81e9af5f10 : 0xffffff80095cf1ba 
0xffffff81e9af6070 : 0xffffff80095ecdff 
0xffffff91fd70bf20 : 0xffffff80095d0459 
0xffffff91fd70bf40 : 0xffffff80094f22fd 
0xffffff91fd70bf90 : 0xffffff80094f27f0 
0xffffff91fd70bfb0 : 0xffffff80095c9117 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
15G31

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Jun 23 18:25:34 PDT 2016; root:xnu 3248.60.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: B5AA8E3E-65B6-3D0E-867B-8DCCF81E536C
Kernel slide:     0x0000000009200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8009400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8009300000
System model name: MacBookPro11,5 (Mac-06F11F11946D27C5)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 2510773395442
last loaded kext at 243272523932: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f8d03f000, size 69632)
last unloaded kext at 1790795658922: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs  1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f8d03f000, size 61440)
loaded kexts:
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    6.0.3
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.22.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.6.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.12.7
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   274.12
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.6f1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.AMDRadeonX4000    1.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.46.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.12.8
com.apple.kext.AMD7000Controller    1.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 86
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTopCaseDriver  86
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1040.1.1a6
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 274.12
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.2.3
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.6f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.12.8
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.4.2
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    205.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   181
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  304.12
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  5
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.4
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro11,5, BootROM MBP114.0172.B09, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2,5 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.30f2
Graphics: AMD Radeon R9 M370X, AMD Radeon R9 M370X, PCIe, 2048 MB
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533642465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533642465238412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x152), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.6f1 17910, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512G, 500,28 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like one of the microcode issues Intel has been fixing on that processor, to me.  Apple doesn't take processor microcode updates seriously, that microcode should be revision 22 at the very least.

That said, it is also possible for that MCE to be caused by memory corruption or signal corruption.